# SciLexer.dll question

Tags: c#, dll, scintilla, scilexer.dll

This may be a silly question, but I need to know it anyway. I am using the Scintilla component in my application, and I was wondering if the user should put the SciLexer.dll file somewhere in their computer when they use the application. If they do, where should it be placed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scilexer.dll assembly should reside in the same folder as your executable so that it could be found at runtime.